# Microsoft Graph User filter with multiple issuerIds

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to filter the Graph (API v1.0) User objects by passing multiple email addresses to filter by. I am able to filter by a single value but can't quite figure out how to write the filter query for multiple values.

I currently have this query which appears to work for $filter

`identities/any(x:x/issuer eq 'test.onmicrosoft.com' and x/issuerAssignedId eq 'user_1@test.com')`

which returns something like the following

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": [
        {
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "unknown",
            "givenName": "test",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": null,
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": "test",
            "userPrincipalName": "bffc1593-ce73-472c-b630-799abb87f79d@test.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "bffc1593-ce73-472c-b630-799abb87f79d"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I write this filter to filter using multiple equality checks by an array of email address?

I've tried the following $filter

`identities/any(x:x/issuer eq 'test.onmicrosoft.com' and ((x/issuerAssignedId eq 'user_1@test.com') or (x/issuerAssignedId eq 'user_2@test.com')))`

`identities/any(x:x/issuer eq 'test.onmicrosoft.com' and (x/issuerAssignedId eq 'user_1@test.com' or x/issuerAssignedId eq 'user_2@test.com'))`

but it returns an error response of **Request_UnsupportedQuery** with the message Unsupported Query.

Can anyone kindly state what the query language is here too? I thought it was kusto but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When filtering users by identities, `issuerAssignedId` and `issuer` properties cannot appear more than once in the filter query.

Also only `eq` operator is supported, so you cannot use `in` operator like this

```
identities/any(x:x/issuer eq 'test.onmicrosoft.com' and x/issuerAssignedId in ('user_1@test.com','user_2@test.com'))
```

Resources:

[User properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the linked resource. I've just tried this query it appears that also errors with **Request_UnsupportedQuery** as it does not support the `in` operator when filtering by identities

Comment: @sharifxu The same error Request_UnsupportedQuery during my testing. Filtering by identities is very limited.